# Python numpy ValueError when I load image data and transfer it to an array

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, array-broadcasting

I couldn't find the solution.My image shape is 128*128*3,it has three channel,but it also cause the error

> File "E:/ML/keras_test/vgg.py", line 30, in load_data data[i,:,:,:] = arr
>
> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (128,128) into
>   shape (128,128,3)

My code as below:

```
def load_data(path):
data = np.empty((12755,128,128,3),dtype="uint8")
label = np.empty((12755,),dtype="uint8")


imgs = []
imgs_name = []
for each_person in os.listdir(path):
    temp = os.path.join(path,each_person)
    for each_image in os.listdir(temp):
        imgs.append(temp + "\\" + each_image)
        imgs_name.append(each_image)  

num = len(imgs)
for i in range(num):
    img = Image.open(imgs[i])
    arr = np.asarray(img,dtype="uint8")
    print arr.shape
    data[i,:,:,:] = arr
    label[i] = int(imgs_name[i].split('.')[0])

print 'load_data is ok!' + str(data.shape[0])
return data,label
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to put the original data into a small package, which is impossible. I think you are trying to transfer a image which has RGB channel into a gray scale image which has one channel. Try

datum = (imgs.sum(axis=2) / 3).reshape((12755, -1))

The resulting `datum` is a `12755 x 16384` array.

Comment: but my image really has RGB channel.And if I have use arr.shape to check it.I am sure each image has three channel

Comment: My image has three channel,then it should be 16384*3 array.So I creat an array which has the shpe(12755,128,128,3). But I don't know why it'll have this error?

Comment: So you want to keep the 3 channels...I misunderstood you. Try explain the target array shape.